# onclick method in android studio is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick

On the click of button the app is not working and the app is being crash.
In the xml file , on the gridlayout I have created button, the working of those button is same for that I have use onClick method, but it is not working

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:onClick="check"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn1">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="check"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:onClick="check"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:onClick="check"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn4">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:onClick="check"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:onClick="check"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:onClick="check"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn7">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:onClick="check"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:onClick="check"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
</GridLayout>
```

for those button I have create check method in the java file
Here is the java file

```
 private void findid() {
//        this method is for find the id of evey reference variable
        btn1=findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2=findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3=findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4=findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5=findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6=findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7=findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btn8=findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btn9=findViewById(R.id.btn9);

    }
    public void restart() {
        count = 0;
        flag = 0;
        btn1.setText("");
        btn2.setText("");
        btn3.setText("");
        btn4.setText("");
        btn5.setText("");
        btn6.setText("");
        btn7.setText("");
        btn8.setText("");
        btn9.setText("");
    }
    public void check(View  v) {
//        this method is for checking the action of the button
        AppCompatButton btncurrent = (AppCompatButton) v;
        if (btncurrent.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            count++;
            if (flag == 0) {
                btncurrent.setText("X");
                flag = 1;
            } else {
                btncurrent.setText("O");
                flag = 0;
            }
            if (count > 4) {
                //after 4th move there is a chance to wining
                b1 = btn1.getText().toString();
                b2 = btn2.getText().toString();
                b3 = btn3.getText().toString();
                b4 = btn4.getText().toString();
                b5 = btn5.getText().toString();
                b6 = btn6.getText().toString();
                b7 = btn7.getText().toString();
                b8 = btn8.getText().toString();
                b9 = btn9.getText().toString();
                //check condition
                //horinzontal conditions
                if (b1.equals(b2) && b2.equals(b3) && !b1.equals("")) {
                    //1
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Winner is " + b1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (b4.equals(b5) && b5.equals(b6) && !b6.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Winner is " + b4, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //2
                }
            } else if (b7.equals(b8) && b8.equals(b9) && !b9.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Winner is " + b7, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //3
            }
            //vartical conditions
            else if (b1.equals(b4) && b4.equals(b7) && !b4.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Winner is " + b1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //4
            } else if (b2.equals(b5) && b5.equals(b8) && !b8.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Winner is " + b5, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //5
            } else if (b3.equals(b6) && b6.equals(b9) && !b9.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Winner is " + b3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //6
            }
            //Dioganal right
            else if (b1.equals(b5) && (b5.equals(b9) && !b9.equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Winner is " + b1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //7
            }
            //Dioganal left
            else if (b3.equals(b5) && b5.equals(b7) && !b7.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Winner is " + b3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else if (count==9){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Match draw", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    }
```

the buttons are not working. when I try to run the app, and click the button the app has crashed.
The error I am getting

```
 --------- beginning of crash
2022-12-27 15:34:48.786 21154-21154/com.sumita.tic_tac_toe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sumita.tic_tac_toe, PID: 21154
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5458)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6412)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25341)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5453)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6412) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25341) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.sumita.tic_tac_toe.MainActivity.check(MainActivity.java:89)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5453) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6412) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25341) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910) 
2022-12-27 15:34:48.805 21154-21154/com.sumita.tic_tac_toe I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21154 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Show the error of your Logcat to know where is the problem

Comment: can you tell me should I copy paste the error? but it is not supporting......
Actually i am very new at android development as well as on this plartform

Comment: When your app crashe, go to your logcat and paste the error, you cant paste the error or what ?

Comment: The comment box is not supporting the error.
Because the length is too long

Comment: Update your question and add your error in your question

Comment: Please check it, I have done that.

Comment: can you show the line of code in line 89 of MainActivity ?

Comment: else if (b7.equals(b8) && b8.equals(b9) && !b9.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Winner is " + b7, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
            }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fount it, I found your problem,
In your condition `if (count > 4)`, if `true` than your `b1,b2, b3.....` will be initialize, if `false` these variable will never be initialize, and in your case `if (count > 4) return false`, so `b7, b8, b9` are not initalize and it cause `null object reference`

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that you solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

What is
`b1 = btn1.getTag().toString();`
It should be getText().toString();

Comment: Yes that should be getText. I have fixed that but the problem is still there

Comment: Show the logcat error maybe that can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to invoke the "equals()" method on a Null object. Which mean, one of those objects is not initialized when you try to call "equals()".

For example, I don't see anywhere in the code the variable "b7" being initialized before used in this portion of your code:

```
else if (b7.equals(b8) && b8.equals(b9) && !b9.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Winner is " + b7, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //3
            }
```

Did you initialized these variables anywhere else?

Tip: Whenever you get this type of errors, use the debug tool in Android Studio, and check where the exception is happening in the code.

Looking at the code, I understand you mean to have the value from "btn7" stored in "b7" for example. In order for the program to work, you need to do that before using the variable "b7":

```
b7 = btn7.getText().toString()
```